# Python decorator to aggregate PyQt signals

Tags: python, pyqt, decorator

I often have many signals that would ideally be processed all at once.  For example, the signal that triggers an update to an OpenGL window can be aggregated into a single signal.  Another example is the signal that dirties a row in a table.

Ideally, I'd like the decorator to generate code something like what's below (between START and END):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from functools import wraps
import signal
import sys

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

class AggregateManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        self.sent = False
        self.value = 0

    def aggregate(self, other):
        send = not self.sent
        self.sent = True
        self.value += other
        return send


class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    # START
        self.generated_signal.connect(self.slot, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.slot_manager = AggregateManager()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def decorated_slot(self, *args):
        me = self.slot_manager
        if me.aggregate(*args):
            print("Sending")
            self.generated_signal.emit()

    generated_signal = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def slot(self):
        me = self.slot_manager
        print("Received", me.value)
        me.clear()
    # END


class B(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)


a = A()
b = B()

b.signal.connect(a.decorated_slot)

for i in range(10):
    b.signal.emit(i)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This way, a single call to `slot` is made for many signals sent to decorated_slot.  How do I use Python decorators to replace everything between START and END?

Comment: how do you decide when you're done populating the sent list (and thus, when to call the combined slot() method)?

Comment: Because the `generated_signal` is connected with a QueuedConnection, the generated_signal is sent immediately on the event loop, but all of the calls to `signal` that happen before that are aggregated.

Comment: Recently I made a system for binding to wxPython events using decorators, maybe you can get some hints from it.  http://bitbucket.org/raz/wxeventbinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have so far.  The only problem is that the pyqtSignal decorator seems to be getting something from the stack trace and there's no way that I know of to override that, which is a clear PyQt design flaw.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from functools import wraps
import signal
import sys

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

class SetAdder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        self.value = set()

    def aggregate(self, other):
        send = not self.value
        self.sent = True
        self.value.add(other)
        return send


# This class decorator adds nameSlot, nameAuxSignal, nameAuxSlot, and
# name_manager.  Signals should be connected to nameSlot.  They will cause
# the function 'name' to be called with aggregated values.
def aggregated_slot_class_decorator(list_):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        for manager_type, name, *args in list_:
            signal_name = name + "AuxSignal"
            slot_a_name = name + "Slot"
            slot_b_name = name + "AuxSlot"
            manager_name = name + "_manager"

            def slot_a(self, *args_):
                manager = getattr(self, manager_name)
                if manager.aggregate(*args_):
                    print("Sending")
                    getattr(self, signal_name).emit()

            def slot_b(self):
                manager = getattr(self, manager_name)
                getattr(self, name)(manager.value)
                manager.clear()

            setattr(cls, slot_a_name,
                    pyqtSlot(cls, *args, name=slot_a_name)(slot_a))
            setattr(cls, slot_b_name,
                    pyqtSlot(cls, name=slot_b_name)(slot_b))

            orig_init = cls.__init__
            def new_init(self, *args_, **kwargs):
                orig_init(self, *args_, **kwargs)
                getattr(self, signal_name).connect(getattr(self, slot_b_name),
                                                   Qt.QueuedConnection)
                setattr(self, manager_name, manager_type())
            cls.__init__ = new_init
            #setattr(cls, signal_name, pyqtSignal())
        return cls
    return class_decorator


@aggregated_slot_class_decorator([(SetAdder, 'test', int)])
class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    testAuxSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def test(self, value):
        print("Received", value)


class B(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)


a = A()
b = B()

b.signal.connect(a.testSlot)

for i in range(10):
    b.signal.emit(i % 5)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Outputs:

```
Sending
Received {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this but on a less generic and more granular scale.  I created a context manager to temporarily disconnect slots.  This way it's clear that you disable certain slots within a block of code then you re-connect them and can emit anything that you missed in between.

The source is [here](https://gist.github.com/durden/5060373) and I pasted the snippet below.  This might not be quite what you want, but it was useful for me in a similar scenario.  I wanted to do something that could emit of 'intermediate' signals where the 'intermediate' changes didn't matter in the long run.  So, with this context manager I can disable the noisy signals and then just emit it once afterwards if needed.  This allows you to avoid a lot of intermediate state changes.

A good example is setting [PyQt QCheckboxes](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcheckbox.html) in a loop.  You could call `checkbox.setChecked()` in a loop but you would emit a bunch of signals for each checkbox.  However, you could use the context manager below to disable any slots for the `stateChanged` signal and the emit the `stateChanged` signal once yourself with the 'final' result.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def slot_disconnected(signal, slot):
    """
    Create context to perform operations with given slot disconnected from
    given signal and automatically connected afterwards.

    usage:
        with slot_disconnected(chkbox.stateChanged, self._stateChanged):
            foo()
            bar()
    """

    signal.disconnect(slot)
    yield
    signal.connect(slot)
```